# Clojurescript - partial function to #js

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

I am calling a native function that has three parameters : `nativeFunction(success, error, options);`

- `success-callback`, a function ex. `function(s) {console.log(s);}`
- `error-callback`, a function ex.  `function(e) {console.log(e);}`
- options (in case it matters) a JSON map

I have a public ClojureScript function like this, wrapping the call :

```
;; this works but I can't separate the success from the failure
(defn ^:export publicFn [cb]
  (nativeFunction. cb cb #js {}))

;; this doesn't work
(defn ^:export publicFn [cb]
  (nativeFunction. (partial cb js/undefined) cb #js {}))
```

So it should be called like that : `myNs.publicFn(function(e, s) {console.log(e, s);});`.

In other words, I would like to be able to convert from the two-handlers convention to a first error parameter convention in ClojureScript, while being compatible with Javascript.

Is it possible ?

Comment: What's the actual issue you're having? Are you receiving an error message?

Comment: @nullptr no error message, no output except for two `undefined`, coming from `VM3162:2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I must have had some other code running, or possibly conflicting, because the following solution works :

```
(defn ^:export publicFn [cb]
  (nativeFunction. (partial cb js/undefined) cb #js {}))
```

I can call it from #js (err JavaScript) like so :

```
myFn(function(e, d) { console.log(e, d); } );
```